# jQuery, how to modify [href] value?

Tags: jquery

For example, want to modify all href value from yahoo.com to google.com

I tried:

```
$("[href='http://yahoo.com']").val('http://google.com');
```

It won't work, what is the correct way to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to replace the "yahoo.com" portion of any `href` with "google.com":

```
$("[href*='yahoo.com']").attr("href", function(i,v){
  return v.replace("yahoo.com", "google.com");
});
```

This works by cycling through all elements that have "yahoo.com" anywhere in their `href` attribute, and replacing that string with "google.com".

```
​<a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">www.yahoo.com</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com?foo">Yahoo?</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Becomes

```
​<a href="http://google.com">Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">www.yahoo.com</a>
<a href="http://google.com?foo">Yahoo?</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Nice, preserve the link structure, just point to another domain! +'d this :)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to set the value property on an element that has none. Instead, you want to set the [href attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), like so:

```
$("[href='http://yahoo.com']").attr("href","http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option like this **working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/CFpeU/ (http://jsfiddle.net/CFpeU/show) **or** http://jsfiddle.net/CFpeU/2/ (http://jsfiddle.net/CFpeU/2/show/)

Prop API: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

code:

```
$(".foo").prop("href","http://www.google.com");​
```

**or**

```
$("[href='www.yahoo.com']").prop("href","http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

To change **ALL** `href` values that contain yahoo.com, you can:

```
$("a[href*='yahoo.com']").prop("href", "http://www.google.com");​
```

**This will work for:**

- http://www.yahoo.com
- www.yahoo.com
- yahoo.com
- etc...

A working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/qMx4G/) to better illustrate the solution!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing that you can try

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/')
```